# CSS fixed div on top

Tags: css

I am making a webiste, and I would like to conciliate a working fixed div on the top of the page (#cssmenu), with the rest (#container). My problem is that these divs are interferiring in to each other. Could anyone be so kind taking a look at it please how not to let the two divs go in to each other?

http://tinyurl.com/l853xsy

Thanks in advance.

Tibor

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Can you elaborate? It looks fine to me. In what way are they "going into each other?"

Comment: try to look at the google maps div, and the top of it, the button of the map is under the header div. there is an <h2></h2> tag hiding under the cssmenu div also.